# Elasticsearch CrateData Compatibily?

Tags: elasticsearch, crate

All,
  I've been playing around with CrateData, and was wondering if you can utilize existing Elasticsearch tools such as drivers and add-ons like Logstash.  For example, can you use an Elasticsearch river (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/) for data ingest, then use the CrateData query engine, etc. against that data? Can incoming JSON objects be mapped to a table? Are there plans to have, or maintain a coexistence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing tools for Elasticsearch with Crate if those tools use the REST API. In order to do so you'll have to enable the es rest api in the `crate.yml` file. There is aa setting to do so:

```
es.api.enabled: true
```

Elasticsearch Plugins won't work without minor modifications as Crate and Elasticsearch aren't binary compatible. Elasticsearch has a shading step in their maven configuration so the elasticsearch jar contains different namespaces then Crate does as Crate doesn't use shading.

So if you wanted to use a plugin you'd have to adjust the namespaces/imports and compile it against crate.